# Debugging code with optimisation flags enabled in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a project with multiple modules. Previously a few core modules didn't have the optmisation flags enabled (Maximise speed /O2). Now, after enabling them, my application compiles and runs, however during run time, I am encountering an error for one of the features. The feature performs as expected without the optimisation flags on.

So, it looks like optimisation is altering the code in a manner that makes the application malfunction - but I am stuck in trying to figure out what is this alteration. Have others faced this problem before? Any suggestions on how should I go about solving it?

Comment: It could be do to a variable that should be marked `volatile` to let the compiler know to leave it alone. Which and where will have to be determined by debugging it. A typical example would be a while loop whose condition is determined by a value that does not get changed inside that loop.

Comment: Build with symbolic debug information enabled (which can be done for optimized builds, too), then debug as usual.

Comment: If you use various STL containers (vectors, maps etc), pass pointers to them from one module (DLL) to another as function parameters or results and these modules are compiled with different optimisation flags, it causes the error because internal implementation of STL containers is different for different optimisation flags.